# Proof Skipped in benchmark

Tags: weight, benchmarking

We're updating our weights to `weights 2.0` but we're getting a lot of `Proof Skipped` lines in the output. What is the impact of this, and how do we fix it?

Example output:

```
/// Proof Skipped: Escrow Locked (max_values: None, max_size: None, mode: Measured)
```

Answer (score 6):

Good question and sorry for the confusion - the comment is poorly chosen.

It indicates that the worst-case Proof Size limit could not be estimated. This can come from either:

- The pallet of the storage item does not expose storage information. You can check this by looking for `#[pallet::without_storage_info]` in the accessed pallet. It needs to be removed in order to have correct proof benchmarking.
- The storage item is not `MaxEncodedLen` bound (MEL). This implies the former. As soon as there is a not MEL bound storage item in a pallet, it cannot expose these storage info.

If your pallet is missing this exact information then FRAME measures the proof size that was required, hence the indication `mode: Measured` instead of `mode: MaxEncodedLen`. The impact is that the results may not reflect the worst-case scenario. So to say; there could scenarios to exploit that and inflate the PoV over the pre-dispatch estimations. In the worst case this means missed block production slots and stalled para-chains.
*However* for relay chains this is not an issue, since they do not produce proofs.
You can basically ignore that for all pallets that will only be used on relay/solo chains.

Storage bounding pallets is not that easy. We [tried](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/8629) in Substrate and it is quite time intensive. One tip is to use the [Preimage](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11649) pallet for large blobs instead of trying to re-implement something like that.

#### MEL

A `T: MaxEncodedLen` bound expresses that all instances of `T` will always encode to at most `MaxEncodedLen::max_encoded_len()` bytes. This is important since it provides up-front information about the worst case storage requirement for encoding any `T`. It is used to calculate the worst-case size of the Proof.

Comment: IIUC, you're saying that proof skipped or the proof-size cannot be estimated iff the pallet uses `without_storage_info` or doesn't use any storage items at all? I have a pallet that doesn't have storage items and I get a lot of `Proof Skipped` messages, thus my question.

Comment: The message was just wrong in a few places. It should disappear with recent Substrate. How is the `without_storage_info` deprecated? Sure it should not be used for parachain pallets, but that was always the case.

Comment: Apologies you're right! I might have confused not using it with deprecated. Thanks for the correction.